# What's the difference between Calendar's getActualMinimum and getGreatestMinimum methods?

Tags: java, date, datetime, calendar, java-calendar

Since `getActualMinimum()` and `getGreatestMinimum()` are going to return the same value for every field what's the exact difference?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate`, `ZonedDateTime` or another appropriate class from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`getActualMinimum()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getActualMinimum(int)) method returns the minimum possible value that an attribute could possibly have.  For example, `Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH` is never less than 1, since no month starts with a day numbered 0 or less.

The [`getGreatestMinimum()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getGreatestMinimum(int)) method returns the maximum possible value that `getActualMinimum()` could ever have.  While in most cases these values will always be the same (months nearly always start with 1), the code allows for them to be different in some rare circumstances.  Using `getGreatestMinimum()` is appropriate for data validation scenarios.

One place this can (and does) occur is when there are skipped dates or discontinuities in a calendar.  Java's `GregorianCalendar`, for example implements dates in the Julian calendar before a cutover date, and the Gregorian calendar after that date, and thus has a gap of several days where dates in the calendar simply don't exist.

The `Calendar` class `getGreatestMinimum()` method is abstract, so it is *required* to be implemented by a subclass.  The JRE's implementation for `GregorianCalendar` shows that it could differ on the `DAY_OF_MONTH` field if the "skipped days" on the cutover month don't include the first of the month:

```java
public int getGreatestMinimum(int field) {
    if (field == DAY_OF_MONTH) {
        BaseCalendar.Date d = getGregorianCutoverDate();
        long mon1 = getFixedDateMonth1(d, gregorianCutoverDate);
        d = getCalendarDate(mon1);
        return Math.max(MIN_VALUES[field], d.getDayOfMonth());
    }
    return MIN_VALUES[field];
}
```

Using this as a cue, you can use `setGregorianChange()` to set the cutover date for Julian-to-Gregorian change. By default it is 15 October 1582 (having skipped 10 days from 4 October 1582).  Different Locales switched at different times, for example Great Britain switched on 14 September 1752 (the day after 2 September).

By setting this cutover to a date in a month that makes the skipped days overlap the first of the month, we can generate these edge cases.

An actual locale-based discontinuity with a real cutover date is probably Romania, in which the day after 31 March 1919 was 14 April 1919.  So in a Romanian locale, the month of April 1919 would only include days from 14 to 30, and `getGreatestMin()` will return 14.

Since I don't have that locale installed I can change the cutover date to simulate what would happen:

```java
GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
// Deprecated, but an easy way of showing this example
cal.setGregorianChange(new Date(1911, Calendar.APRIL, 14));
System.out.println("actual min = " + cal.getActualMinimum(cal.DAY_OF_MONTH));
System.out.println("greatest min = " + cal.getGreatestMinimum(cal.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

Output:

```
actual min = 1
greatest min = 14
```

Another edge case exists if you use `Date(Long.MIN_VALUE)` as the cutover, giving a "pure Gregorian" calendar with no gaps. But in that case, the "beginning of time" is on the 16th of the month (in the Gregorian calendar), so greatest min in that case is 16.

Other calendar systems may have similar discontinuities and edge cases.

Comment: I meant greatestminimum

Comment: I've updated my answer (and edited your question) with that clarification, and a specific example of where they differ.

Comment: One last question, If the field value is January 15 1990- how the actual minimum will be calculated? It compare January of every year to get actual minimum? Or the year 1990 alone?   And also how GreatestMinimum works in reference to the above context?

Comment: @SangitaElango it applies to the entire calendar in use, regardless of the current date set in the calendar.  For this particular calendar (`GregorianCalendar`) the only really interesting parts are that Julian/Gregorian cutover point. However, anyone could implement any calendar type with strange rules like, perhaps having February start on the 2nd in non-leap years, or having occasional 3-day weeks, etc.  These methods are meant for validation/special handling use.

Comment: I don't know the concept of accept and upvote. I'm new to stack overflow FYI.

Comment: Looks like you figured it out!

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you stop using the outdated and error-prone `java.util` date-time API. In the modern date-time API, the `smallestMaximum` refers to the smallest of the maximum values e.g. the maximum number of days for the month ranges from `28` (for `Feb`) to `31` and therefore the `smallestMaximum` is `28`.

Similar is the case with `largestMinimum` whose name is self-descriptive. However, unlike the `smallestMaximum` which holds the smallest value from the **range of maximum values**, I haven't been able to find the **range of minimum values** from which the largest value has to be held by the `largestMinimum`. In other words, the values held by `minimum` and `largestMinimum` are same for all the `ChronoField`s.

### [With the modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html):

```
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // e.g. Value range for ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH
        System.out.println("Stats of ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH:");
        System.out.println("Supported value range: " + ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH.range());
        System.out.println("Maximum supported value: " + ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH.range().getMaximum());
        System.out.println("Minimum supported value: " + ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH.range().getMinimum());
        System.out.println("Largest minimum supported value: " + ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH.range().getLargestMinimum());
        System.out
                .println("Smallest maximum supported value: " + ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH.range().getSmallestMaximum());

        // e.g. Value range for ChronoField.DAY_OF_YEAR
        System.out.println("\nStats of ChronoField.DAY_OF_YEAR:");
        System.out.println("Supported value range: " + ChronoField.DAY_OF_YEAR.range());
        System.out.println("Maximum supported value: " + ChronoField.DAY_OF_YEAR.range().getMaximum());
        System.out.println("Minimum supported value: " + ChronoField.DAY_OF_YEAR.range().getMinimum());
        System.out.println("Largest minimum supported value: " + ChronoField.DAY_OF_YEAR.range().getLargestMinimum());
        System.out.println("Smallest maximum supported value: " + ChronoField.DAY_OF_YEAR.range().getSmallestMaximum());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Stats of ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH:
Supported value range: 1 - 28/31
Maximum supported value: 31
Minimum supported value: 1
Largest minimum supported value: 1
Smallest maximum supported value: 28

Stats of ChronoField.DAY_OF_YEAR:
Supported value range: 1 - 365/366
Maximum supported value: 366
Minimum supported value: 1
Largest minimum supported value: 1
Smallest maximum supported value: 365
```

Check [`TemporalAccessor#range`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAccessor.html#range-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-) for more details. Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Comment: Curious if the new date-time API has the same Julian-Gregorian discontinuity for largest minimum as the old Calendar (as referenced in my answer).

Answer (score 1):

There is no such method as leastminimum . The methods are getActualMaximum(), getActualMinimum(), getLeastMaximum(),getMaximum() and getMinimum()

getLeastMaximum() would return 28, getMaximum() would return 31,
getMinimum() would return 1    for input as Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK

The methods with 'Actual' will return the corresponding least or max values specific to the calendar instance value being used. ( Some calendars have 13 months in a year)

So the Actuals are relative and the other 3 methods are absolute.

I just read through the java doc and the below 2 links to arrive at this conclusion

[getActualMaximum()](https://javatutorialhq.com/java/util/calendar-class-tutorial/getactualmaximum-method-example/)

[getActualMinimum()](https://javatutorialhq.com/java/util/calendar-class-tutorial/getmaximum-method-example/)